# Ratios of Wishart Quadratic Forms

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a general way of using Jacobians to determine the pdf of the ratio of two quadratic forms using two different functions of the same sample Wishart matrix $ \Sigma $. For example

$ a = \frac {V^T \Sigma^m V }{V^T \Sigma^n V } $

A simple example is the ratio $ a = \frac {V^T \Sigma V }{V^T \mathbf E [\Sigma] V } \sim \chi^2_{N-1} $, for arbitrary $V$  quoted in corollary 3.2.9 of Muirhead's statistics book.